# Simple Logarithmic Growth with Limit Function

Tags: calculus

I need to simulate population growth that slows as it reaches the population maximum.

Each time the simulation ticks I want to figure out how much I grow my population by, towards a max limit.

So, starting at zero I would have big growth that would get smaller and smaller per tick as I reach MaxPopulation.

I would assume it'll use Log, but I don't know how to integrate the variables below to make it work.

**Variables:**

- CurrentPopulation.
- MaxPopulation.
- Growth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are probably interested in is [logistic growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) The link has all the formulas you need.

Briefly, the population $P(t)$ at time $t$ is given by an equation of the type
$$P(t)=\frac{KP_0e^{rt}}{K+P_0(e^{rt}-1)}.$$

Here $P_0$ is the population at time $t=0$ (you can select $t=0$ as you wish). 
The number $r$ is the growth rate when population is small and resources are plentiful. The number $K$ is the "limit" population size.

**Added:** If you are interested in the growth **rate**, the formula is quite a bit simpler. If $P=P(t)$ is the population at time $t$, then the growth rate at time $t$ is usually denoted by $\dfrac{dP}{dt}$. The formula for growth rate is
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=rP\left(1-\frac{P}{K}\right).$$
Just like before, $K$ is the limiting population size, $r$ is a constant that gives the rate of growth if resources were not limited, and $P$ is the *current* population.

The formula even works if current population happens to be greater than $K$. It then predicts a negative growth rate.

Comment: hah. I caught that first link you made and was utterly confused. Looks like logistic growth is exactly what I am after, however I am still struggling to place my variables into it properly. Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, had copied a link for myself, and it was still in the cache. I have added a bit of information. You will find many hits under logistic growth, or Verhulst model. You can plug in your own numbers. Like $0.02$ for $r$, say.

Comment: Sorry, my math skill is limited: What is 'e' in this case and can I remove the t (time step) variable as I only need to compute the grwoth factor given the limit and current size.

Comment: The number $e$ is a basic mathematical constant, about $2.72$. Any scientific calculator, or Google, will compute $e^x$ for you. The growth factor changes with time, and becomes very tiny as we approach the population limit.

Comment: Thanks. However I asked for the growth rate, not the total population size at time t.

Comment: I will add a few lines about the growth rate, it will take $10$ minutes or so.